# Postpone Postback For 3 Seconds?

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a usercontrol with a couple of drop downs Lists and a button, I want the user to click the button (Which response.redirects depending on the selection in the DDL's).

Now instead of redirecting straight away, I want to display a little loading icon for 3 seconds and then redirect...  Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Have I done anything like this?  No, because it's retarded.  But if you want to do it, it's straightforward.  Instead of redirecting, show the loading box and set a timer that calls your function when the timer is done.  Easy.  But pointless.

Comment: Is this so you can "optimise" the slow loading pages later?

Comment: lol.. I know its lame, but needed as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

In the postback

Answer (score 3):

An artificial delay where none is needed is kinda lame.  What you can do instead is on submission of your form display your throbber.  I use the following on a document upload form where large media files are being posted.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="PreJavaScript">
    function NUsubmit(){
        document.getElementById("uploadFormInputs").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("progressBar").style.display = 'block';
        return true;
    };
    function init() { document.getElementById("UploadFormObject").onsubmit = NUsubmit; };               

    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

If I remember correctly, in some versions of IE the animated gif didn't play but it worked fine in IE6+ and FireFox.

This way if the postback is quick they never see the throbber but if it takes a while they see it and it gives them the sense that something is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform delays with the setTimeout() function in javascript.

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('After 5 seconds.'); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need to override a couple things in your Javascript and use a "setTimeout" to delay the loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var __handleSubmit = theForm.submit;
    theForm.onsubmit = function() {
        alert('loading'); //Show your message here
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            __handleSubmit();
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

*You might want to play with a bit more... this is may not work for all instances since I've never done it.*

If the delay is simply for "aesthetics", to make it appear it is working, then I'd recommend against it - programmers appear to be the only people that think loading bars are cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should implement this page using AJAX.  You can place a progress indictor on your page to alert the user that a long running process is taking place.